# Subtracting 2 Dates using DateComponents gives undefined behavior

Tags: swift, date, nsdatecomponents

Given the following method I added to the Date object in an extension:

```
extension Date {
    static func -(left: Date, right: Date) -> DateComponents {
        let components: Set<Calendar.Component> = [
            .year,
            .month,
            .day,
            .hour,
            .minute,
            .second,
            //.weekOfYear, // issue!
        ]

        let gregorian = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
        let dateComponents = gregorian.dateComponents(components, from: right, to: left)
        return dateComponents 
    }
}
```

And given the following dates (format is Month Day, Year, hh:mm:ss) you get 1:

```
let day1 = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: 1516003200) // January 15, 2018, 00:00:00
let day2 = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: 1516089600) // January 16, 2018, 00:00:00
let diff = day2 - day1
print(diff.day!) // 1
```

But given the following dates, you also get 1:

```
let day3 = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: 1515916800) // January 14, 2018, 00:00:00
let day4 = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: 1516089600) // January 16, 2018, 00:00:00
let diff2 = day4 - day3
print(diff.day!) // 1
```

So my first question is wondering **why the day difference is the same even though one of the pair is 1 day apart and the other is 2 days apart.**

Finally, given the following dates, you get the correct number of 14:

```
let day5 = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: 1516089600) // January 16, 2018, 00:00:00
let day6 = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: 1517299200) // January 30, 2018, 00:00:00
let diff3 = day6 - day5
print(diff3.day!)
```

But if you were to go back to `static func -(left:right:)` and uncomment `.weekOfYear` and re run the above block of code with `day5` and `day6` you get 0 days. So my second question is **why I'm getting 0 days if I add the** `.weekOfYear` **component to the Set.**

I included two screenshots of a playground below, first one with `.weekOfYear` not included and the second one including `.weekOfYear`:

[image: <code>.weekOfYear</code> commented out]

[image: <code>.weekOfYear</code> included]

Comment: day 3 - day4 I get 2 days you are printing the wrong var `print(diff.day!)` when you should be printing `print(diff2.day!)`

Comment: I ran a test with your `day3` and `day4`, testing every time zone, and in all of them, the `day` difference is 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the following code

```
let day3 = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: 1515916800) // January 14, 2018, 00:00:00
let day4 = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: 1516089600) // January 16, 2018, 00:00:00
let diff2 = day4 - day3
print(diff.day!) // 1
```

you are using `diff.day` when in fact you should be using `diff2.day`

As for your second issue, the calendar will return date components by assigning from the maximum to minimum. That is to say that when you add `weekOfYear`, it assigns a value of 2 to `weekOfYear`. If you were to print out `diff3.weekOfYear`, you will get 2 (because the dates come up to be 2 weeks). Since there are no days left behind after the date is converted into weeks, you get 0 days for `diff3.day`. If you were to use the dates `Jan 16th` and `Jan 31st`, you would get a value of 2 for week and 1 for day